# API automation - convert JSON in to a string without "\ operator without any formatting

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured, java-17

Within the method, it couldn't pass the JSON payload without formatting (`\` and `""` operator).

```java
public static String psotrequest() {

   String payload = "{"
       "\"name\":\"morpheus\","
       "\"job\":\"leader\"
   }";

   return payload;

}
```

But is there a way to pass the request payload like the following?

```java
public static String psotrequest() {

   String payload = {
      "name":"morpheus",
      "job":"leader"
   };

   return payload;

}
```

Which library or JAR file will help us pass a direct request payload in a Java class without using `"\"`or `"\n"`?

Answer (score 0):

A string in Java is defined by double quotes `""`. There isn't any way to define it as you wish. But in Java 15, it has a [text block](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html) feature that might help.

For example, put the JSON structure inside `"""` and `"""`.

```java
String payload = """
   {
      "name":"morpheus",
      "job":"leader"
   }
""";
```

Comment: Hi Lucas,  In my method can we pass the json structure without formatting? like 
  :  public static String test()
{
  String payload1 = {
        "name":"morpheus",
        "job":"leader"
     };

     return payload1;
}  - tried not working...

Comment: Pls, re-read my answer.

Comment: Hi Lucas,  Thanks for the help. It works. While running the java program am getting  "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Comment: @Samson it'd be another question with more information. If my answer solves your problem, pls accept my answer.

Comment: As conveyed in the previous message. It works. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Samson then accept the answer and upvote it, it's how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: have only 9 reputation  I tired multiple time to vote but am unable thanks for the help and sorry for the inconvenient.

Comment: using text block can we pass the dynamic value in my JSON payload  like  public static String updateputrequest()
 {
  String putss = """
   {
        "name": "sandy",// how to pass the dynamic value 
        "job": "leader"
    }
    """;
                     return putss;
       
 }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74946421/java-se17-api-automation-block-text-java-class-how-to-pass-dynamic-value

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Step 2: Create a class like below

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonCoverter {

    public static JSONObject Convert_Json_To_JsonObj(String Filename) throws IOException, ParseException {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(Filename));
        JSONObject inputpayload = (JSONObject) obj;
        return inputpayload;
    }


}
```

Step 3: Save your *body* in a JSON file with a .json extension

Step 4: Now use the above **Convert_Json_To_JsonObj** method in RestAssured.

```
given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(JsonCoverter.Convert_Json_To_JsonObj("src/test/resources/requestJson/YOUR_JSONFILENAME.json")).
        when()
                .post("").
        then()
                .statusCode(200);
```

Comment: Add a dependency to what? Some build system?

Comment: What is "RestAssured"? What does it refer to?